# Java Spring boot async method isn't being called occasionally

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a service with a method annotated with `@Async` as below:

```
@Service("AsyncService")
public class AsyncService {
   @Async
   public void asyncPrint() {
       logger.info("Inside asyncPrint");
   }
}
```

The async method is called from another service like this:

```
@Service("CallerService")
public class CallerService {
   @Autowired
   private AsyncService asyncService;

   public void caller() {
      logger.info("Before asyncPrint");
      asyncService.asyncPrint();
      logger.info("After asyncPrint");
      // Custom code
  }
}
```

However, I'm seeing that sometimes the async method is not being called. I can see the before and after logs, but the async log is not printed.

Sample o/p:

```
//Logs from other services
Before asyncPrint
After asyncPrint
Inside asyncPrint
//Logs from other services
Before asyncPrint
After asyncPrint
```

Why could this be happening? Can async tasks be dropped if there is a backlog in the Executor? Also, is there a way for me to see how many of the total running threads are being used by the async? Or how else can I debug this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The log doesn't mean your Async method isn't being called, it means the Executor hasn't called it yet. The @Async uses a `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` by default with unlimited queue capacity. This means ALL your tasks will be queued until processing threads become available.

If you want to increase your processing Threads you can defined a custom `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` bean as below.

```
  @Bean
  public Executor taskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
    executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
    executor.setThreadNamePrefix("GithubLookup-");
    executor.initialize();
    return executor;
  }
```

Where you can play with corePoolSize and maxPoolSize according to your hardware specifications.

Comment: Thanks. But it actually does look like the message isn't being logged at all. Unless it is stuck in the backlog of the queue for a really long time, because I can see the messages from the following requests. I'm assuming there is no way to see how many tasks are in the backlog, is there?

Comment: @drunkenfist You can use `taskExecutor().getThreadPoolExecutor().getQueue().size()` to see the number of queued tasks.